# Setting Visibility using MVVM pattern in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I take one grid in silverlight. Initially textbox2 is invisible. When I click on textbox1 we have to  visible  textbox2. I try it as belows:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textbox1" SelectionChanged="txt1_SelectionChanged"/>
<TextBox x:Name="textbox2 "  Visibility="Collapsed"/>

private void txt1_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    textbox2 .Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

It works fine.

But I want to use MVVM pattern. So there I don't want to use eventHandler.
So how to do that using MVVM pattern?

Comment: Which version of Silverlight are you using?

Comment: MVVM is not no code behind.  If you have code that only affects the View, then you are not violating MVVM to have code behind.  In fact, putting View logic in your ViewModel does more to go against MVVM than a simple event handler.

Answer (score 5):

edit: sorry, i thought you meant the textbox to be visible when the other one has focus, I changed my inital answer.

I can not try it at the moment, but you bind the Visibility property of your textbox to the SelectionLength property of the other, using a valueconverter:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:IntToVisibilityConverter x:Key="IntToVisibilityConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<Textbox 
  x:name="textbox2" 
  Visibility={Binding SelectionLength, 
              ElementName="textbox1" 
              Converter={StaticResource IntToVisibilityConverter}}
/>
```

implement the value converter like this:

```
public class IntToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter 
{
  public Object Convert(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    return (int)value > 0 ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
  }

  public Object ConvertBack(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
  {
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Converter cannot convert back.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Although this may be a fine solution, it is not answering the question:  How to do it using MVVM?

Comment: I don't understand, what else is there to do? All is done in property binding without any code-behind or viewmodel needed.
If the question was indeed about a viewmodel, he can create one and bind the Visibility and SelectionLength properties to it. OP, please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Create a property in viewmodel

```
 public bool IsVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return _isVisible;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_isVisible == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _isVisible = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsVisible");
        }
    }
```

This returns a boolean value so u need a converter BoolToVisibility Converter make BoolToVisibilityConverter class

```
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (parameter == null)
        {
            return ((bool)value == true) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else if (parameter.ToString() == "Inverse")
        {
            return ((bool)value == true) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Now Bind the TextBox and use the converter

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <local:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
 </UserControl.Resources>

 <Textbox x:name="textbox2" Visibility={Binding IsVisible,
          Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}/>
```

This is it.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem you will have is getting the SelectionChanged event sent to the ViewModel. Commands in SL4 only work on button clicks, so TextBox SelectionChanged events can't fire commands by default.

There are a few solutions out there for you:
[Binding Commands to ANY event](http://houseofbilz.com/archives/2009/08/27/adventures-in-mvvm-binding-commands-to-any-event/)
[EventToCommand Behavior](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/11/05/mvvm-light-toolkit-v3-alpha-2-eventtocommand-behavior.aspx)

Once you have done that, you can have a command in your ViewModel that sets a Visibility property in your ViewModel and fires the PropertyChanged event.

Using my [ViewModelSupport library](http://houseofbilz.com/archives/2010/05/08/adventures-in-mvvm-my-viewmodel-base/), the VM would look like this:

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  public Visibility ShowTextbox2
  {
    get { return Get(() => ShowTextbox2, Visibility.Collapsed); }
    set { Set(() => ShowTextbox2, value); }
  }

  public void Execute_SelectionChanged()
  {
    ShowTextbox2 = Visibility.Visible;
  }
}
```

}

You would then bind the SelectionChanged event to the SelectionChanged command in the VM and the Textbox2 visibility attribute to the ShowTextbox2 property in the VM.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVVM Light, you can also do it like this:

```
using System.Windows; //place it at the top of your view model class.

private Visibility _isVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;

public Visibility IsVisible
{
    get
    { return _isVisible; }

    set
    {
        if (_isVisible == value) { return; }

        RaisePropertyChanging(() => IsVisible);

        _passwordMissing = value;

        RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsVisible);


    }
}
```