# I unable to get child control from ListBox control in WPF using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am in serious trouble. I have listbox control in which i have many combo box. whenever select the value in combo box, i have to make other controls as hidden. i am using MVVM pattren. i am unable to get the child controls from ListBox control but i can get the ListBox control in viewmodel. How can i get these controls in viewmodel? Is it possible? I am using framework 4.0. i have shown the code below which write in view.

```
  <ListBox x:Name="lstItems" MaxHeight="300" FontSize="11" Margin="12,0,20,38" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource listedView}, Path=myItemsSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Blue" Margin="0,4,0,4" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="Show rules where:" Name="lblshowrules"></Label>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="cboShowRuleWhere" Height="20" Width="200"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource listedView}, Path=FilterRules}" DisplayMemberPath="RuleName"  SelectedValuePath="RuleId" SelectedValue="{Binding Source={StaticResource listedView}, Path=SelectedRuleName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" ></ComboBox>
                        <Grid Height="29" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="496" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                            <ComboBox Height="21" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,4,0,0" x:Name="cboRuleCondtion"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="212" />
                            <TextBox Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="242,3,0,0" x:Name="txtValue" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="245" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                            <ComboBox Height="21" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="224,3,0,0" x:Name="cboValue" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="205" Visibility="Hidden" />
                            <DatePicker Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="242,-3,0,0" x:Name="dtpFromDate" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="98" Visibility="Hidden" />
                            <DatePicker Height="31" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="346,-3,0,0" x:Name="dtpToDate" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="98" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Button Name="cmdAddLevel" Padding="0" Margin="-1,1,0,-1" Width="75" Command ="{Binding Source={StaticResource listedView}, Path=AddLevelCommand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Height="25" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Height="16" Width="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1,0,0,-1">
                                </Image>
                                <TextBlock Text="Add Level" FontWeight="Bold" Height="16" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="8,2,0,-1" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
                        <Label Name="lblDeleteLevel"  Margin="3,0,0,0" Width="75" TabIndex="7"  HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <Hyperlink >
                                <TextBlock Text="Delete Level" />
                            </Hyperlink>
                        </Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
```

Please help me. once again, i want to know how to get the child control from parent control... Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Using the MVVM pattern, you should not be referencing any of the controls directly. Alternatively, you should create a boolean property on your viewmodel that decides if various controls should be visible. Then bind the Visibility property of the controls you want to hide to this property, using a converter.

See this previous Q/A for details on visibility converters: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100524/setting-visibility-using-mvvm-pattern-in-silverlight)